Web-Proxy error (Fortimanager) conflict issue on fortimanager
I need support regarding an issue with the web-proxy. How can we resolve this issue where FortiManager is pushing changes to FortiGate, causing a conflict on the firewall?
Starting log (Run on device)
Start installing
Goa_firewall  config system global
Goa_firewall (global)  unset gui-theme
Goa_firewall (global)  end
Goa_firewall  config system settings
Goa_firewall (settings)  unset gui-wireless-controller
Goa_firewall (settings)  unset gui-traffic-shaping
Goa_firewall (settings)  unset gui-fortiextender-controller
Goa_firewall (settings)  unset gui-file-filter
Goa_firewall(settings)  end
Goa_firewall  config web-proxy global
Goa_firewall (global)  set proxy-fqdn ''
value parse error before ''
Command fail. Return code -56
Goa_firewall (global)  end
---> generating verification report
(vdom root: web-proxy global:proxy-fqdn)
remote original:
to be installed: ''
<--- done generating verification report
------- Start to retry --------
Goa_firewall  config web-proxy global
Goa_firewall (global)  set proxy-fqdn ''
value parse error before ''
Command fail. Return code -56
Goa_firewall (global)  end
---> generating verification report
(vdom root: web-proxy global:proxy-fqdn)
remote original:
to be installed: ''
<--- done generating verification report
install failed
expecting to resolve the conflict issue on fortimanager.
